# how can I append divs with seperative classes on click dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with a link inside of it. as you see in snippet when the link is clicked it appends a new div beside. it is working!

but what i want is when every time link is clicked a new seperative class should be dynamically adding to 'project-list'.

```js
 $(".click").click(function () {
  $(".container").append('<div class="project-list"><div class="projects-name"> div1</div><div class="project-box">Content</div></div>');
});
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%
  }
 .project-list{
   width:100px;
   background:#e8e8e8;
   border-radius:5px;
   padding:10px 20px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:8px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
      <div class="project-list">
         <div class="projects-name"> div1</div>
          <div class="project-box">Content</div>                             
           <div class="ProjectSetting">
              <a class="click" href="#">click</a>
            </div>                         
       </div>
   
</div>
```

if it is not clear ask me below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var i=0;
 $(".click").click(function () {
 i++;
 var toAppend = '<div class="project-list newClass'+i+'"><div class="projects-name"> div1 [newClass'+i+']</div><div class="project-box">Content</div></div>';
 
  $(".container").append(toAppend);
});
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%
  }
 .project-list{
   width:100px;
   background:#e8e8e8;
   border-radius:5px;
   padding:10px 20px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:8px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
      <div class="project-list">
         <div class="projects-name"> div1</div>
          <div class="project-box">Content</div>                             
           <div class="ProjectSetting">
              <a class="click" href="#">click</a>
            </div>                         
       </div>
   
</div>
```